# Android, Image Adapter, Null Pointer Exception in getCount()

Tags: android, gridview

I want to use an integer to set how many images the image adapter adds to the gridview rather than the length of the array, but when I put anything else in getCount() it always gives null pointer exception. I need to set this because I'm randomly adding the images to the grid, I want a certain amount of images displayed in the grid depending on an integer that was parsed from the previous activity. I also tried making some if statements to check if diff was 2 or 3 and if so it would return the length of one of the other arrays and I set an else statement so if diff was any other number it would use the current arrays length, but this also gave a null pointer.

So how do I make it add a dynamic amount of images to my gridview rather than the length of one array?

```
Integer diff, gridSize, randomPosition, item;
GridView grid;
ImageView img;
Random rng;
ImageView imageView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    grid = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
    grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    rng = new Random();

    Bundle pack = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    diff = pack.getInt("dif");

    if (diff == 1){
        gridSize = 16;
        grid.setNumColumns(4);
    }

    if (diff == 2){
        gridSize = 25;
        grid.setNumColumns(5);
    }

    if (diff == 3){
        gridSize = 36;
        grid.setNumColumns(6);
    }


public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return gridSize; // this used to return mThumbIds.length by default and it worked then
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
            randomPosition = rng.nextInt(gridSize);
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3); 
            } 
            else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            imgSet();
            return imageView;
    }

    public void imgSet(){
        if (diff == 1){
            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[randomPosition]);
        }
        if (diff == 2){
            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds2[randomPosition]);
        }
        if (diff == 3){
            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds3[randomPosition]);
        }
    }
```

I then have my arrays of images under this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this before set image adapter

```
if (diff == 1){
    gridSize = 16;
    grid.setNumColumns(4);
}

if (diff == 2){
    gridSize = 25;
    grid.setNumColumns(5);
}

if (diff == 3){
    gridSize = 36;
    grid.setNumColumns(6);
}
```

let me know if it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Set your adapter ***after*** getting the value of 'diff' and 'rng', like so:

```
grid = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
rng = new Random();

Bundle pack = this.getIntent().getExtras();
diff = pack.getInt("dif");

if (diff == 1){
    gridSize = 16;
    grid.setNumColumns(4);
}

if (diff == 2){
    gridSize = 25;
    grid.setNumColumns(5);
}

if (diff == 3){
    gridSize = 36;
    grid.setNumColumns(6);
}

grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```